# Javascript execution order and callbacks

Tags: javascript

I know that the following code:

```
function do_a(){
  // simulate a time consuming function
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log( '`do_a`: this takes longer than `do_b`' );
  }, 1000 );
}

function do_b(){
  console.log( '`do_b`: this is supposed to come out after `do_a` but it comes out before `do_a`' );
}

do_a();
do_b();
```

Results in

```
`do_b`: this is supposed to come out after `do_a` but it comes out before `do_a`
`do_a`: this takes longer than `do_b`
```

Well first of all, I'd love to understand WHY - how does javascript decide to "move on" and execute the faster code first.

Secondly, why doesn't this solve the problem - i.e. why does the alert happens before the for loop is done?

```
 function doit(start,callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { 
        document.getElementById('edit-cut').innerHTML = "<div></div>";
    }
    callback(start);

 }

 var start = Date.now();
 doit(start,function(start){
        var end = Date.now();
        alert(end-start);
 });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about `setTimeout`? What is not clear about it?

Comment: lol. you seem a little confused about how `setTimeout` works. It's not a `sleep`. Google `javascript event loop`.

Comment: There's multiple questions on this topic. I strongly suggest you search first because I'm tired of answering this for the 100th time (and marking duplicate for the 200th time)

Comment: FWIW, to simulate a time consuming function, do `var end = Date.now() + 5000; while (end > Date.now());`. This will execute a while loop for 5 seconds.

Comment: Ah, oops, my bad folks. I did know that stuff about setTimeout, to be honest I meant something else and pasted the code from another site. My question is more towards the second section with the DOM update - it has been answered below and I'm trying to read into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Well first of all, I'd love to understand WHY - how does javascript decide to "move on" and execute the faster code first.

It doesn't execute the "faster" code first. It executes code in the order that it is told to.

You run do_a. You run do_b. The JS event loop looks for the next function to run. There isn't one. After a second has passed, the timeout finished and the function you passed to it gets put on the queue to run. The event loop runs that function.

> why does the alert happens before the for loop is done?

It doesn't. You're confusing updating the DOM with updating the display.

Repainting the script is effectively a function. The for loop updates the DOM. The for loop finishes. Then the alert runs. The alert blocks until the user clicks the button. All this is strictly linear. The event loop is busy running that JS.

Once your JS function has finished, the browser repaints the screen and puts the results of updating the DOM on the display.

This is why, to update the DOM in a loop like that you would typically use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` calls the function after the specified time. Actually JS moves on to execute b and executes your anonymous function after the specified time. Your first method does not simulate a time consuming function. Instead it configures the intepreter to call your anonymous function after 1000 ms (asynchronous to the other code).